# Using curl instead of http request 2 in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use curl instead of the http request 2 pear module in PHP to query the plivo api. They have an existing library for easily making calls to their API but it uses a pear module called http request2. I don't really know how to install a pear module on a server so I thought of just rewriting some parts of their library to just use curl.
Here's the part of their code that I specifically want to modify:

```
function __construct($auth_id, $auth_token, $url="https://api.plivo.com", $version="v1") {
    if ((!isset($auth_id)) || (!$auth_id)) {
        throw new PlivoError("no auth_id");
    }
    if ((!isset($auth_token)) || (!$auth_token)) {
        throw new PlivoError("no auth_token");
    }
    $this->version = $version;
    $this->api = $url."/".$this->version."/Account/".$auth_id;
    $this->auth_id = $auth_id;
    $this->auth_token = $auth_token;
}

private function request($method, $path, $params=array()) {
    $url = $this->api.rtrim($path, '/').'/';
    if (!strcmp($method, "POST")) {
        $req = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
        $req->setHeader('Content-type: application/json');
        if ($params) {
            $req->setBody(json_encode($params));
        }
    } else if (!strcmp($method, "GET")) {
        $req = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
        $url = $req->getUrl();
        $url->setQueryVariables($params);
    } else if (!strcmp($method, "DELETE")) {
        $req = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_DELETE);
        $url = $req->getUrl();
        $url->setQueryVariables($params);
    }
    $req->setAdapter('curl');
    $req->setConfig(array(
        'timeout' => 30,
        'ssl_verify_peer' => FALSE,
    ));
    $req->setAuth($this->auth_id, $this->auth_token, HTTP_Request2::AUTH_BASIC);
    $req->setHeader(array(
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'User-Agent' => 'PHPPlivo',
    ));
    $r = $req->send();
    $status = $r->getStatus();
    $body = $r->getbody();
    $response = json_decode($body, true);
    return array("status" => $status, "response" => $response);
}

  public function get_account($params=array()) {
    return $this->request('GET', '', $params);
}
```

And here's the code that I have so far:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'auth_id:auth_token',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Connection: close", "User-Agent: PHPPlivo"),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30

);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I don't really know what's going on behind the scenes but this specific code is telling me that its using basic authentication using the values for the auth id and auth token:

```
$req->setAuth($this->auth_id, $this->auth_token, HTTP_Request2::AUTH_BASIC);
```

So I also set it using curl:

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'auth_id:auth_token',
```

I'm pretty much stuck. All I get as a respose is the following:

```
{
  "error": "not found"
}
```

It doesn't really make much sense into what I have missed or done wrong. Please help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Below are the things you need to handle to sync your new code with old one:

If you are using `GET` method

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/'.http_build_query($params),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("User-Agent: PHPPlivo"),
```

If you are using `POST` method

```
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-type: application/json", "User-Agent: PHPPlivo"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea... The PEAR dependency is definitely overkill for Plivo's wrapper. So that was one of the first modifications I made to the code.

Check out: 
https://github.com/ashbeats/Plivo-Curl-Based-Wrapper/

Only difference is the `RestAPI::request()` method.